# Have a texbox with "tag" like behavior in wpf?

Tags: wpf

Lets say i have a TextBox control that the user can type in, I want the textbox control to behave similiar to the "Tags" textbox that appears right below, where i type something in the textbox, i show a list of suggestions, when the user selects a suggestion I pop it in the textbox and display a small button.

I have wired up the TextBox, with the ListBox showing in a popup with the suggestions and I even go the selection of the suggestions working, I am strugglinh with making the button appear and dissapear when the user backspaces etc.

Requirements: I need to have ONLY One Tag.

Problems: I want the button to be inside the texbox, but it appears outside right now.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

My Xaml:

```
        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="8"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button Content="Res" Grid.Column="0" Width="30" x:Name="tagbutton" /> <!-- This is the tag button i want to collapse show. -->
                            <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" 
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     PreviewKeyDown="SearchTextBox_PreviewKeyDown"
                                     KeyUp="SearchTextBox_KeyUp" 
                                     Margin="0,2,0,0" FontSize="14" 
                                     Padding="3" 
                                     Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=100}">                            
                            </TextBox>
 <Popup x:Name="suggestionPopup"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=outerBorder}" 
               Placement="Bottom"                
               IsOpen="False"
               StaysOpen="False"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               Margin="0,23,0,0">
           <MyListBoxHere>
        </Popup> 
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Could you not just use a normal auto complete text box like this one? https://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to appear inside the `TextBox` control, you will need to override the control template for `TextBox` to create a custom control that will allow that.  The standard `TextBox` control will only accept `string` (or numeric values) as content.

You can make it look like the button is inside the textbox with something like:

```
    <Border Width="120" Height="35"
            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Width="70" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
            <Button Content="myTag" Margin="4"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

[image]

You can then change the styling on the `TextBox` to be borderless and be the same color as your border object, and then it would look like the button is inside the textbox.  Your `Border` control becomes the new outline of the "textbox".